# Cannot create Ember object from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have a problem with creating Ember objects from a JSON ajax data source. If I create the object the manual way, it works perfectly, and the view gets updated. If the data itself comes from a JSON ajax data call, however, it does not work. If I inspect the resulting objects, the Ember model objects does not get the correct getter and setter properties. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
App.AlbumView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'album',
    albums:[],
    getAll:function() {
        var self = this;

        //This works!
        self.albums.push(App.Album.create({title: 'test', artist: 'test'}));

        $.post('/Rest/list/album',null,function(data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                //This does not work?!?
                self.albums.push(App.Album.create(item));
            });
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please do an alert on item to see what is the output. alert(item);

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a POST request rather than a GET to get data from the server

Comment: Can you put up a JSfiddle at least of the bits that work so I can have a poke at it?  I'm interested but don't know enough of the rest of your setup to understand the problem fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use embers `get('variableName')` and `set('variableName', newValue)` methods  when accessing instance variables of a view. Strange things tend to happen if you don't.

Comment: Views don't implement get and set. When I try calling them, I get 'no such function' errors.

Comment: Views implement get and set since these methods are defined in Ember.Observable, which Ember.View extends (via Ember.Object). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zentralmaschine/uh74U/1/

Comment: I see. Strange. Well, it seemed to work when I moved the collection to a globally accessible ArrayController, and I guess the use of get and set makes the difference. So I accept the answer. I will try to debug the view problems seperately, then.